# WPF XAML Styles not applying properly (.NET 5)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I'm trying to apply 2 custom styles to 2 Buttons on a UserControl.

Here I have the Styles defined in a Buttons.xaml ResourceDictionary which is properly registered as a ResourceDictionary in App.xaml.

```
<!-- Contained button -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MaterialContainedButton">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundLightBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="64" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border 
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Medium" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryLightBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<!-- Outlined button -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MaterialOutlinedButton">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="64" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border 
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="3">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Medium" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundLightBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the two Buttons on my UserControl are defined as follows:

```
<StackPanel 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Orientation="Horizontal" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button 
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialOutlinedButton}"
            Content="CANCEL"
            Margin="10"
            />
        <Button 
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialContainedButton}"
            Content="SAVE"
            Margin="10"
            />
    </StackPanel>
```

I have 2 problems with this code:

1. For some reason the BorderThickness Property in the second style doesn't apply to its respective Button.
2. The Buttons differ in Height although they should have the same Height based on their styles

All other styles in my Buttons.xaml file work just fine, it's just these two that just don't seem to work as they should. If anyone has any idea how to solve this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Add `BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"` to the Border in the second ControlTemplate.

Comment: The second style does not have a `BorderThickness` setter.  So naturally it's not changing anything.

Comment: @Joe There is `BorderThickness="1"` on the Border element.

Comment: So there is.  Ignore me :-)

Comment: @Clemens Adding the BorderBrush fixed it. Thank you!